# WSO2 Governance Service Audit

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is there a way to show entire Audit Log associated to one service in the Service Detail layout instead of having to go search activities & figuring out changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, It is not supported yet. You need to search in log file using the service name and found out them.  Actually for analysis logs and audit, WSO2 may recommend the BAM server where you want to publish server's audit and log data